# How to build a Collection View Controller with top and bottom white?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, storyboard

I suppose to build a collection view controller like this.
[image]
[image]

However, the new collection view controller I built has a collection view cell sticking on the left top side. It looks different when I adjust the size of the collection view and put a navigation bar inside. The length of the navigation bar is restricted in the collection view cell. The bottom side has no blank space as well.

[image]
[image]

How can I build a collection view controller with top and bottom white?

Comment: If you want your collection view to be resizable, better use your own `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You can do collectionView inside of viewController and adjust the size of the collectionView cell size depending on your choice, feel free to check out the sample below. :)

[image]

For you to be able to achieve the News at the top, you have to go to your controller then Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller then on your controller you have to declare this on your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationItem.title = "News"

}
```

However for your white space on top and bottom of your collectionView you have to declare the top space and bottom space of it for you to be able to achieve it.

[image]

Comment: Not really this case. I have a collection view when I build the collection view controller. I modified the question to make it more clear. Would u like to take a look?

Comment: What look exactly you want to achieve ? Do you want to have a news on the top of your collectionView or news inside of the collectionView?

Comment: I want to have a news on top of the collection view and also have space at the bottom like the one shown in the first picture.